# State Preservation and restoration issue

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7

In my application, I need to make a call, So obviously my app go to background while making a call using native call feature.if the call goes long my app is getting killed by IOS itself. Now i need to restore the last view at the time of making a call. I have used Native restoration. **What i did is**

**1. Set the restoration ID for all the views and view controllers.**

**2. Override the app delegate restoration methods.**

My Issue is,
If my app go to background and come back to foreground, Last view is displayed using preservation and suddenly moved to main view(Default launch view). just like last view blinking while coming to fore ground.

Here is my setting:

app Delegate code :

```
-(BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    return YES;
}
-(BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application shouldRestoreApplicationState:(NSCoder *)coder
{
    return YES;
}
-(BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application shouldSaveApplicationState:(NSCoder *)coder
{
    return YES;
}
-(BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application willFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    return YES;
}
```

Main view settings :

[image]

Main storyboard contains the login view as a root. Please guide me to fix the restoration issue.

Comment: Could be that your app is receiving a memory warning and its memory is getting purged. I had noticed this kind of behaviour in iOS 7.

Comment: I am facing the same restoration issue in simulator itself.

Comment: check this link [State Preservation and Restoration](http://useyourloaf.com/blog/2013/05/21/state-preservation-and-restoration.html). that will help you.

Comment: @pawan: i am not using tab bar controller. i have created two sample with that document one with tab bar controller as a root with and another is navigation controller as a root view. preservation failed in second case.

Comment: it should work fine with your app flow. but still if you have problem , you can send  your test code to me,  i will check once.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to get rid of the blinking by making the window key and visible in `application:willFinishLaunchingWithOptions:`.

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application willFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
    return YES;
}
```